# How swift manages memory

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I have two view controller in swift "A" and "B". Let I have some variable in A. So after initialization, it stored in Memory area. Then what happen, when I moved to B view controller. The memory gets released or still there in the memory space ?

Comment: `when i moved to B view controller` — how exactly ? Different transitions may work differently. Also, it's not `swift memory management`, but `UIKit` architecture question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by moved to B? ..you mean present to B ViewController from A?

Comment: Swift works like Objective-C, with reference counts.  Every strong reference increments the count.  Weak references do not.  If both A and B have strong references then the memory will not be released.  If only A view controller has a reference, and A view controller is released, then the memory is released.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Memory can be either static, stack or heap. Depending on the type of the variable (global, instance, local) and the type of the value you store into it (string literal, value type, reference type) this can have different answers.

Answer (score 1):

As long as view controller A is still present in the view controller hierarchy, it will still be strongly referenced and any variables that it strongly references will still be in memory.

If you had previously presented A and then dismissed it, then A and its variables would potentially have no strong references and would no longer be in memory.